# EPiServer shared VPP folders

Tags: episerver, fileshare

This might be at daft question but i've nerver done it before...

We are a few developers on the same project with local development environments and now we want to set up shared VPP folders on a external server.

I have created a VPP folder on the external "testserver" but how do i configure it to be shared by all the developers in the project?

Answer (score 4):

They need to modify **episerver.config** file. Find *virtual path* section and change the *physicalPath* value.
e.g.

```
<add showInFileManager="false"
     virtualName="Page Files"
     virtualPath="~/PageFiles/"
     bypassAccessCheck="false"
     indexingServiceCatalog="Web"
     physicalPath="\\test_server\VPP\PageFiles"
     name="SitePageFiles"
     type="EPiServer.Web.Hosting.VirtualPathVersioningProvider,EPiServer"
/>
```

Comment: The element you want to look at is in <episerver><virtualPath><providers>. It may be in your web.config or an external config file like episerver.config depending on the project setup.

Comment: You may come across another problem if you work remotely and can't access the file share. I sometimes keep the VPP folder with the project files and use a relative path (see https://gist.github.com/778715). And then check in the VPP folder to source control too so the whole project can be checked out on any machine by any developer. Of course if the VPP folder is very large it's best to keep it on a network share and not clog up your source control repo.